# Quotient relation on complex field

Tags: complex-numbers, equivalence-relations

How to make quotient relation on complex field, each equivalence class of which consist of only 2 elements?

Comment: Are we allowed to exclude $0$, i.e. to look for relations on $\Bbb C^\times = \{ z \in \Bbb C \mid z \ne 0 \}$?

Comment: You mean using of conjugate numbers? There are no specifiecations in the conditions about it. Is it possible to make it with 0 ?

Comment: I don't know if it can be made to work with $0$; without $0$, the relation $a \sim -a$ evidently works; also $a \sim -\bar a$.  With $0$, things might have to get discontinuous; I just don't really know . . . anyway, nice question, ***endorsed!!!***

Comment: Also, $a \sim \bar a$ won't work since the reals are each in a singleton equivalence class

Comment: I don't know if it can be done with $0$; if we are allowed to exclude $0$, I thing the $\Bbb Z_2$ actions  $a \to -\bar a$ might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no other requirements than that every equivalence class has two elements, then there are many ways to go about it.

For example, we can define $x + iy \sim u + iv$ if and only if $y = v$ and $\lfloor \frac x2\rfloor = \lfloor \frac u2\rfloor$ and $x - \lfloor x\rfloor = u-\lfloor u\rfloor$. I.e. if the binary expansions of $x$ and $u$ are the same except for possibly the 1 bit.

As Robert Lewis suggests, the map carrying $z$ to its sole equivalent is not continuous in this example. Nor does it respect the field properties of $\Bbb C$. If you want an equivalence that does either, things become much tougher.

Comment: So, in your suggested variant equivalence is  iff only if y=v and ⌊x/2⌋=⌊u/2⌋ and x- ⌊x⌋=u - ⌊u⌋ ? So all of these three conditions must comply, or its enough one of them? What will be in relation with 0 ?

Comment: "and" means all of them. Otherwise you don't get exactly 2 elements. And note the other explanation of this equivalence: two numbers are equivalent if their real parts have the same binary expansion, except for the 1's bit. Change the 1's bit of $0$ to $1$, and you get the number $1$, which is its only equivalent.

Comment: Prompt me, please, what will in relation with 3/4? With √(2) ? Thank you

Comment: In binary, $3 = 11_b$, so changing its 1-bit becomes $10_b = 2$. $4 = 100_b \sim 101b = 5$. $\sqrt 2 = 1.011..._b \sim 0.011..._b = (\sqrt 2 - 1)$. More generally, the equivalent to any number $x$ will be either $x + 1$ or $x -1$, depending on whether the 1-bit of $x$ is $0$ or $1$.